# Unable to display all the thumbnail images as a thumbnail slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added code for thumbnail sliders it should display all the thumnail images and should move one by one.It is working fine for mobile devices but getting problem in desktop.It is displaying only one image and it is sliding but i need to display all the images and the image should slide one by one.

```
                              <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel"> 

     <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
     <!-- Quote 1 -->
     <div class="item active">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/gallery/01.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

 <!-- Quote 2 -->
<div class="item">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/gallery/02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

This is the code which i have added.

Here is the fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/5j07ogyc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/01.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/02.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/03.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/04.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/01.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/02.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/03.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="images/gallery/04.jpg" class="img-responsives">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi
                                    doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio
                                    similique suscipit</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
(function () {
    $('#carousel123').carousel({ interval: 2000 });
    $('#carouselABC').carousel({ interval: 3600 });
}());
(function () {
    $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function () {
        var itemToClone = $(this);

        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

            // wrap around if at end of item collection
            if (!itemToClone.length) {
                itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
            itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
                .addClass("cloneditem-" + (i))
                .appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
}());
```

solved by adding this as a slider and responsive